# How to isolate server disaster script in PHP?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Oh my goodness. I never thought that I will need to ask you this. But unfortunately yes, I need to!

I have a PHP written script of my own that uses ffmpeg-php. And ffmpeg-php is a bastard. For some input it works ok, but for some it crashes my whole PHP and server throws Internal Server Error 500. I've tried several times to update ffmpeg-php, ffmpeg itself and so on, but when for some input it works in version 0.5 in 0.6 it wont work. And what i need is be sure that rest of the script will be processed correctly. And now it does not, because when it comes to run toGDImage() on movie frame I have Internal Server Error 500 and no feedback why from any source.

So for peace of mind of my users I decided that I need to isolate this part of script that messes with ffmpeg-php. I need a way to assure that if something will go terribly wrong in this part, it rest will go on.

Try catch does not work because this is not a warning, nor a fatal error, it is a horrible server-disaster. So what are your suggestions?

I think about putting this script into another file called ffmpeg-php-process.php and call it via HTTP and read result, if it is Internal Server Error 500 - I will know that it was not ok.

Or are there any other, more neat ways to isolate disaster scripts in PHP?

Ps. Don't write that I need to diagnose or debug or find the source of the error. I'm not a damn beginner and I'm not a ffmpeg dev to mess in it's code, I need to make my users safe now, and it's everything that i care now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting a 500 error, it's because an exception of some sort is being thrown at a level lower than that of PHP itself. Unless your code is spinning into some kind of infinite loop or hitting a recursion limit (and especially since it worked with version 0.5), there's a good chance that ffmpeg or ffmpeg-php is crashing and taking the instance of PHP that launched it down with it.

Frankly, there's nothing you can do from PHP.

Your best bet would be, since you've already got access to the server, to write the script in question using a language like Python. There's a ton of ffmpeg python plugins, so you shouldn't have a difficult time setting that up at all. Call your Python script from PHP and pull in the output from a file. What this will do is isolate PHP from your script failing. It'll also get you away from ffmpeg-php (which, at least to me, seems like an unholy combination).

If you're dead-set on using PHP (which I don't recommend), you can launch another PHP script using php-cli from your outward-facing PHP script and do the work from there (as you would with Python). Again, I highly recommend that you avoid this.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You could spawn a new process containing your php-ffmpeg script. There are some functions to do that: `proc_open()` as instance.

The documentation has a not bad example about it:
http://php.net/proc_open

Comment: Would be the best isolation. You could even automate workers with  `gearman` & `multiwatch`

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar going with a convoluted, large, bulky legacy php-email system I support.  When it got apparent that the email system was becoming it's own beast, we split it off as its own virtual server entirely.  There's no separation like PHYSICAL separation.  And hey, virtual servers are cheap....

On the plus side, you can start, restart, and generally destroy the separate server with little affect on the rest of your code.  It may also have improved backup implications (isolate media and logic)  Since going this route, we've not ever taken the main application server down.

However, it does create a connection challenge as now rather than working local you're going to have your server talking to another separated by at the very least a bit of wire in the same cabinet (hopefully)